# PeerConnectionClient example Conductor instantiation

Tags: c++, webrtc

... for the WebRTC example in main.cc is as follows:

```
talk_base::scoped_refptr<Conductor> conductor( new talk_base::RefCountedObject<Conductor>(&client, &wnd));
```

Can someone elaborate what's going on, esp. why the need for a reference counted conductor and why custom smart pointers?